# switching between frames or windows in scilab

Tags: user-interface, scilab

Hi I am new to scilab and I am working on a small gui application and I want to know if there is a way to make the callback function of push_button switch to another window. What should I write in the body of a callback function ? And if so can i load a .sce file that contains the code of the other window directly ?

Comment: Switching to another window/figure is not a problem by itlsef (use scf() command). But what do you mean by "code of the other window" ? Windows in Scilab are just figures for graphics and/or widgets (uicontrols).

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet I mean like if I had the script of the other window that I want to show, in another .sce file how can I load it in the function's body ? For example, I have window2.sce that is the script of the second window, what to do to have the pushbutton loads that window2 and switch from window1 to window2. Does that make sense ?

Comment: Just use exec("window2.sce") in the callback.

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet Thank very much ! you saved the day :p